# Add custom function to child function.php

Tags: child-theme, pre-get-posts

I am trying to add a custom function to remove a particular category from my blog page of the website. I got the code right in parent function.php but when I try to add the same code to my child function.php, the code does not work at all.

The code i am using is below:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-338' );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

I don't want to use this code in the parent function and want to use the same in child function.php.

FYI- I am using betheme for wordpress

Comment: maybe in the parent theme the code on the same hook override this code. try to set a bigger priority for this code.

Comment: Are you sure the child theme is in use?

Comment: Yes. I am using the child theme and its activated. I tried to set the priority to 1, 15 and 20 but every time I get error 500 after setting the priority.

Comment: How did you set the priority? If you use something like `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category', 20 );` there should be no 500 error.

Comment: It was a very silly mistake which I was making. Instead of add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category', 20 ); I was using add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' 20); didn't put the comma in the middle. Thanks for correcting me @swissspidy